# Firing JavaScript inside a C# WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, javascript, flash, browser

Trying to write an app that searches a WebBrowser control in C# and get the elements of a flash page.  Problem is with Flash you don't have access to all of the DOM objects and if Firebug I get something like:

```
<div>
  <div class="nvbar_start"></div>
  <div class="nvbar_middle">
    <a **onclick="ajaxLinkSend('globalContainer', 'quests.php');** return false;" href="javascript:;">
      <span class="hover_header">Quests</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nvbar_end"></div>
</div>
```

Thus I cannot fire the OnClick event...  Tried researching and I know it the answer is here but evidently I'm asking the wrong question.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks
Wayne

Comment: If you can find your required elements using Firebug then you _should_ be able to find them with JavaScript / C# methods. Try running JavaScript on your page through Firefox using the Scratchpad (Shift + F4) or the Firebug script console. Test whether you can find the required elements using this method before attempting to progress.

Comment: try using UFRAME which is a jquery plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you can trigger the event with javascript then in the WebBrowser Control you can `wb.Navigate("Javascript:DoFoo();");`

Use a browser console window to figure out the necessary javascript for this (if it is even possible in your context).